# PYTHON : Finding hidden element in html source code

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying get the url below which is hidden inside the page source code at https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32212764152.html but it's hidden inside a script tag.

```
<script>
                    window.runParams = {"descriptionModule":{"descriptionUrl":"https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com/product/description/pc/v2/en_US/desc.htm?productId=32212764152&key=HTB1GwO_aVY7gK0jSZKzM7OikpXac.zip&token=f32528ddd34e37aecddda1c7778d5f0c"} .... </script>
```

I've manage to get the source code but not sure how to extract the url as an object.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import re

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/driver/chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32212764152.html')

html = driver.page_source

def run_script():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP)

count = 0
while count < 3: #13
     run_script()
     count+=1
     time.sleep(5)

x = html.startswith('https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com')
print(x)
```

How do I filter everything else in the source code and have an object ?

x = "https://aeproductsourcesite.alicdn.com/product/description/pc/v2/en_US/desc.htm?productId=32212764152&key=HTB1GwO_aVY7gK0jSZKzM7OikpXac.zip&token=f32528ddd34e37aecddda1c7778d5f0c"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression to extract the value:

```
import re
#..
url = re.compile(r'"descriptionUrl":"([^"]*)"').search(html).group(1)
```